# Why am I receiving this IO exception when querying a Hive table using SparkSQL in Zeppelin?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I followed the first part of [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/) to create an external Hive table and point it towards a specific S3 Bucket. In the Hue interface, I can browse a sample of the data after a successful creation. If I switch over to Zeppelin and run the following command: `%sql show tables` I can see my table listed next to the `default` database.

Now, if I actually try and query the table, I get a `java.io.IOException: Not a file: s3://my-bucket/my-subdirectory` error. The error makes sense, but Hive makes you specify an S3 bucket and not an actual S3 file, so I'm not sure how to make both happy!

Note, there is only 1 file in this directory and I'm not attempting any partitioning. The file is compressed and named `foo.txt.gz` and was generated using `psql` and dumping a postgres table.

Edit: showing code

### Create Script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
  name STRING,
  age INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-directory/'
```

### Querying In Zeppelin

```
%sql SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 100

java.io.IOException: Not a file: s3://my-bucket/my-directory
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext.showDF(ZeppelinContext.java:235)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkSqlInterpreter.interpret(SparkSqlInterpreter.java:130)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:95)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:490)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is potentially some listing confusion here related to the fake directory markers that the blobstore clients put in after a mkdir() call, markers they are *meant* to remove after actually creating files there.

that *may* be creating confusion

Have a look in the S3 browser in the AWS web pages, and look for a blob "my-directory/". If it is there, delete it